# What is the best practice for associations and view restrictions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails app to teach myself associations. Its an app with Tutors and Students where Tutors create Students as Users and can then Tutors create "posts" for what was taught in that lesson to the specific Students page to show their progress. When the Student logs in they can only see their assigned progress and do nothing else.

I figured an option is having Students as "categories" so the Students can be filtered but what is the best practice?

It seems simple but I keep overthinking it

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to create the associations as you need them in your code later. So if a tutor has many students and many posts and a student has many posts and belongs to a tutor and so on.

In order to restrict it in the view, you can restrict that in the controller. So this is where you can filter the posts by the students then. So you could do `student.posts` (Beware, I am not super sure what your db structure/schema looks like).

And there are gems that handle authorization. Look at [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) (my favorite) or [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). With those you can specifiy for each controller action, who can see/do certain things.

Now judging from the little information you gave, you might also want to look into namespaced controllers because you probably have a `posts#index` for tutors and another one for students. Here you can get another layer of organisation by adding a so called namespace meaning you can have one posts controller under tutors and one under students. You can find more info here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Let me know if anything is unclear!